# What does increased Luck do?

Tags: borderlands-3

I just got an artifact with a stat I've never seen before in a game in the franchise.

It says it gives me +8.33 Luck.

[image]

What exactly does this do? Do I get better/more loot? More money? Or is it just a tiny hidden cosmetic effect like [+ Friendship in Borderlands 2](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Mysterious_Amulet)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Luck is a stat that determines how often you get rare, very rare, and legendary loot drops in the game. This stat can also be seen in your Guardian Ranks, where its labelled "Luck (Rarity Rate)"